# All the if statements in my controller (ruby on rails) are being treated as true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I honestly can't understand why this is happening, and I've tried everything (even creating situations where they possibly can't be true).

For example:
let's say I'm trying to go through all the courses a student has previously taken. So maybe I set something up like:

```
          student.courses.each do |course|
            if course.name = "COMP1900"
               @test = 'hit'
            end
          end
```

This returns true just as it would in this situation:

```
          student.courses.each do |course|
            if course.name = "C0pm19abagdastgeagesdgs"
               @test = 'hit'
            end
          end
```

Obviously that isn't going to be true, but it returns it as true anyways. And not just this if statement. It does it for EVERY if statement. No matter what it's dealing with: Projects, assignments, students, courses. Using names, dates, anything. I don't understand what's happened because at other parts in the code previously if statements work as they should. I'm very confused and have no idea what's happening. It even outright skips code block sometimes. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 5):

It's because in Ruby `=` is used for **assignment**.

After it assigns the object, the return value is the object itself, which is *truthy*.

In your case you want to use the **comparison operator** `==`.

```
course.name == "COMP1900"
```

Comment: Tried that too before as well. Still triggers for some reason. Actually, it didn't just trigger. It outputted duplicate assigned values. So that's not it I guess?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "duplicate assigned values"?

Comment: So for example a student might be assigned to the outputted list twice...sometimes. But not all the time. Also sometimes when the value is actually true (such as if course.name == "COMP1900"), it will still output false. What I'm trying to do right now is see if a student has already taken a course, so student.precourses is meant to be an array (placed in @precourses = student.precourses) and I'm going through all the courses in the database (@courses.each do |course|) and see if @precourses.include?(course.name)

Comment: Maybe you are expecting each block to return false? each block will always return back the array. Also, I don't understand your set up. Is precourse and course different models?